# Ajax Posting from popup form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that loads in a popup div layer. I also have a `saveForm()` function that makes an AJAX post request.

How can I take the value from the two input fields into that `saveForm()` function?

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value=""><br><br> 
Description: <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value=""><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="saveForm()">Save</button>
```

```js
function saveForm() {
  $.post("save.php", {
    user_id: '1234'
  }, function(data, status) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: you want to save form data with POST method ? right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the two fields separate `id` attributes then get their values and set them as properties of the object you provide as the body of the request to send in the AJAX request.

It's also worth noting that you should avoid using `on*` attributes in your HTML where possible. It's better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers. As you've already included jQuery in the page, that can be done using `on()`, like this:

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""><br><br> 
Description: <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value=""><br><br>
<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#save').on('click', function() {
    $.post("save.php", {
      user_id: '1234',
      name: $('#name').val(),
      description: $('#description').val(),
    }, function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Better still would be to put the elements in a `form` and change the `button` to `type="submit"`. Then you can hook to the `submit` event of the form. This is in order to improve accessibility and the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

you can send post with data like this example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = $("#your-form-id");
var data = $(form).serialize(); 
$.ajax({
    url: "your-url/save.php",
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        //your js after success post
    }
});
</script>
```